# Symfony2 and Assetic, dump/watch assets with Vagrant on NFS

Tags: symfony, vagrant, assetic

I'm having some problems with generating my css+javascript assets on symfony2 in my dev environment.

The situation is as follows
The application runs on a vagrant-box and the files are shared. Most developers use NFS (host=linux+osx), one is using the default VirtualBox sharing (host=windows).

The problem happens when work is being done on less/js files.
I prefer to run

```
./app/console assetic:watch
```

As this should pick up any changes on disk and prepare the new css/js files based on what is currently in the less/js files, so we can see if it is what we want.

Because of the network share it can take some time before the vagrant box picks up the changes made (this can be quite a lot of time).

I'm looking for a solution where those changes are picked up almost instantly after changing them in an IDE on the host-system.

Answer (score 0):

Rhodri Pugh posted a solution for your problem in his blog post "[Symfony Vagrant Assetic Woes](http://blog.pu-gh.com/2014/04/30/symfony2-vagrant-assetic-woes/)"

***It's pretty straight forward:***

<kbd>1</kbd> Download FSWatch

```
cd /tmp && \
    wget https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/releases/download/1.5.1/fswatch-1.5.1.tar.gz -O fswatch-current.tar.gz
```

Note: As of today, latest releaste is v1.5.1, but you can check the latest [here](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/releases).

<kbd>2</kbd> Untar archive

```
mkdir fswatch-current && tar -zxvf fswatch-current.tar.gz  -C /tmp/fswatch-current --strip-components=1
```

<kbd>3</kbd> Install FSWatch

```
cd fswatch-current && ./configure
make
make install
```

<kbd>4</kbd> Just use it

```
fswatch src/My/Bundle/Resources/public | while read line; \
  do app/console assetic:dump --env=assetic; done
```

Comment: has that to be used on guest or host os?